# VBA wordapp.document.open and selection.WholeStory

Tags: vba, ms-word

Thank you in advance to looking and helping.

I'm trying to open a word document, then run some code on the document's contents, and save it.  Here's what I have:

```
wordApp.Documents.Open (strFile)
wordApp.Visible = True
wordApp.Selection.WholeStory

strAll = wordApp.Selection.XML
```

This seems to get a handle to the contents of the document being opened.  I can change search it, etc, and it appears to be changing the contents, however when I attempt to save it:

using this:

```
wordApp.ActiveDocument.Save NoPrompt:=True
```

or using this:

```
wordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=folderName + "\test.xml", FileFormat:=wdFormatXML
```

the actual saved file isn't changed.  If the actual document isn't being changed, and yet the changes are being made, where would the changes being made?

I can actually open the document, not as part of processing a folder, but opening it manually and run an action that has the same code in it and it makes the changes and prompts me to save when I close it.  The ValidateFolder is the sub.  It opens all .xml documents in a folder and validates contents, then I need to save any changes.  The code for the whole things is:

```
Private Sub ValidateFolder_Click()
    Dim wordApp
    Dim folderName As Variant
    Dim fileDir As String
    Dim strAll As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim arrString() As String, occurInStr() As String, fldVal As String
    Dim logResults As String
    Dim dispVal As String
    Dim i As Integer, v As Integer
    Dim lnCount As Integer
    Dim charPos As Long

    folderName = BrowseForFolder("C:\")
    lnCount = 0

    If folderName <> "" Then
        MsgBox ("check " + folderName)

        fileDir = Dir$(folderName + "\*", 16)

        Do While fileDir <> ""
            If fileDir <> "." And fileDir <> ".." Then
                Rem If entry is an xml file, then check the file.
                If InStr(1, fileDir, ".xml", 5) > 0 Then
                    Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.Application")
                    strFile = folderName + "\" + fileDir
                    wordApp.Documents.Open strFile
                    wordApp.Visible = True
                    wordApp.Selection.WholeStory

                    strAll = wordApp.Selection.XML
                    arrString = Strings.Split(strAll, "»")
                    MsgBox ("Opened: " + strFile)
                    MsgBox (CStr(strAll))

                    For i = 0 To UBound(arrString)
                        'MsgBox (CStr(UBound(arrString)))
                        fldVal = strRight(arrString(i), "«")
                        'MsgBox (fldVal)
                        If fldVal <> "" Then
                            fldVal = fldVal & "»"
                            occurInStr = Split(fldVal, "»")
                            'MsgBox ("Match-" & CStr(i + 1) & ": " & fldVal & " occurances: " & CStr(UBound(occurInStr, 1)) & " error occur: " & CStr(InStrRegEx(fldVal, "«[A-Z_! ,d+0-9]*<.*»")))

                            If InStrRegEx(fldVal, "«[A-Z_! ,d+0-9]*<.*»") > 0 Then
                                Dim repVal As String

                                repVal = leftOfStrRightBack(fldVal, ">")
                                repVal = strRight(repVal, "<")

                                Dim newFldVal As String
                                newFldVal = Replace(fldVal, repVal, "")

                                Dim myRange As Range
                                Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
                                myRange.Find.Execute FindText:=newFldVal, Forward:=True

                                If myRange.Find.found = True Then
                                    myRange.Find.Execute FindText:=newFldVal, ReplaceWith:="FLDSTART" & newFldVal, Format:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                                End If

                                Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
                                myRange.Find.Execute FindText:="FLDSTART", Forward:=True

                                If myRange.Find.found = True Then
                                    myRange.Find.Execute FindText:="FLDSTART", ReplaceWith:="", Format:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                                End If

                                logResults = "errors"
                                If logResults = "" Then
                                    logResults = "The Following Fields had errors:" & Chr(10) & "   " & newFldVal
                                    MsgBox (logResults = "The Following Fields had errors:" & Chr(10) & "   " & newFldVal)
                                Else
                                    logResults = logResults & Chr(10) & "   " & newFldVal
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next

                    If logResults = "" Then
                        MsgBox ("No errors")
                    Else
                        MsgBox ("errors")
                    End If

                    If logResults = "" Then
                        logResults = "Success!" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "There were no detected errors in fields."
                    Else
                        logResults = logResults & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "They have been fixed." & Chr(10) & "Please save this document."
                    End If
                    MsgBox (logResults)
                    Rem Saving and closing the document.
                    wordApp.ActiveDocument.Save NoPrompt:=True
                    MsgBox ("Save and Quit now")
                    'wordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=folderName + "\test.xml", FileFormat:=wdFormatXML
                    'wordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs (folderName + "\" + fileDir
                    'MsgBox ("Saved")
                    Exit Sub 'Stop here so you process only one document for testing.
                    wordApp.Quit SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges, OriginalFormat:=wdWordDocument

                End If
            End If

            fileDir = Dir$()
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
Function BrowseForFolder(Optional OpenAt As Variant) As Variant
    Dim ShellApp As Object

     'Create a file browser window at the default folder
    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application"). _
    BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, OpenAt)

     'Set the folder to that selected. (On error in case cancelled)
    On Error Resume Next
    BrowseForFolder = ShellApp.self.Path
    On Error GoTo 0

     'Destroy the Shell Application
    Set ShellApp = Nothing

    'Check for invalid or non-entries and send to the Invalid error
    'handler if found
    'Valid selections can begin L: (where L is a letter) or
    '\\ (as in \\servername\sharename.  All others are invalid
    Select Case Mid(BrowseForFolder, 2, 1)
    Case Is = ":"
        If Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = ":" Then GoTo Invalid
    Case Is = "\"
        If Not Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = "\" Then GoTo Invalid
    Case Else
        GoTo Invalid
    End Select

    Exit Function

Invalid:
    'If it was determined that the selection was invalid, set to False
    BrowseForFolder = False
End Function

Public Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    MsgBox (fldr)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = OpenAt 'Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
Public Function leftOfStrRightBack(ByVal searchIn As String, ByVal searchFor As String) As String
    Dim charPos As Long
    Dim retStr As String

    retStr = ""

    If InStr(1, searchIn, searchFor, 5) > 0 Then
        charPos = Len(searchIn)
        While charPos > 0
            If CStr(Mid(searchIn, charPos, 1)) = searchFor Then
                'MsgBox ("Searched: " & searchIn & " found: " & searchFor & " at pos: " & charPos)
                retStr = CStr(Mid(searchIn, 1, charPos))
                'MsgBox ("Return: " & retStr)
                GoTo BreakOut
            End If

            charPos = charPos - 1
        Wend

BreakOut:
    End If

    leftOfStrRightBack = CStr(retStr)
End Function
Public Function strRight(ByVal searchIn As String, ByVal searchFor As String) As String
    Dim charPos As Long
    Dim retStr As String
    retStr = ""
    charPos = InStr(1, searchIn, searchFor, 5)
    If charPos > 0 Then
        retStr = CStr(Mid(searchIn, charPos, Len(searchIn)))
    End If
    'CStr(CStr(Mid(arrString(i), charPos, Len(arrString(i))) & "»"))
    strRight = CStr(retStr)
End Function
Public Function InStrRegEx(ByVal searchIn As String, ByVal searchFor As String) As Long
    Dim regEx As Object, found As Object
    If Len(searchIn) > 0 And Len(searchFor) > 0 Then
        Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        regEx.Pattern = searchFor
        regEx.Global = True
        regEx.IgnoreCase = True
        Set found = regEx.Execute(searchIn)
        If found.Count <> 0 Then InStrRegEx = found(0).FirstIndex + 1
    End If
End Function

Public Function getText(ByVal searchIn As String, ByVal searchFor As String) As String
    Dim regEx As Object, found As Object
    If Len(searchIn) > 0 And Len(searchFor) > 0 Then
        Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        regEx.Pattern = searchFor
        regEx.Global = True
        regEx.IgnoreCase = True
        Set found = regEx.Execute(searchIn)
        If found.Count <> 0 Then getText = CStr(found(0))
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Selection.XML returns a string that represents the document markup (or just the text, if you use the DataOnly switch). Essentially it's a copy of the document, not the actual document itself. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.xml

Comment: Thank you.  So if I continue to use this would you know how I save this updated dataonly selection to a word document?  I'm willing to create a new one and then remove the old one, I just don't know what I need to do to save out this updated selection.  Thank you again.

Comment: Can you explain a bit about what your goal is with this code? If you're doing text manipulation, there are better objects. If you're doing XML formatting, VBA is not the best tool for the job.

Comment: Well, I'm utilizing an existing VBA tool and working in the ability to find and replace issues found, updating the documents.  Instead of doing it one open document at a time, this feature will check all documents in a folder.  The issues are in the field values.  Sometimes they contain html characters, but aren't visible except by grabbing the XML.  My code finds the problems and does a find/replace to correct it, but I'm still still trying to somehow make my selection.xml the myrange value.  MyRange works, but I need to get the results back into the selection.xml.  Thank you again.

Comment: Thanks for the info. From the double angle quote marks in your code, can I assume these are mailmerge fields? Or some other kind?